# How to get dynamic sub documents [No Array] from a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

There is a collection like this

```
MongoDB Enterprise datap:SECONDARY> db.employee.find({"id":"12345"},{rltns:1});
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("XXXXX"),
    "rltns" : {
        "MO" : {
            "field1" : "hi",
            "field2" : "hello",
            "field3" : "aloha",
            "field4" : "namaste",
            "field5" : "oi",
            },
        "FA" : {
            "field1" : "check01",
            "field2" : "check02",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Number of different relationships can be 0, 1 or multiple

We need to print data for only id and field1/field2

How to get those in the following format?

```
12345 | MO | hi | hello
12345 | FA | check01 | check02
```

Comment: What the '12345' represent, and which langage do you use ?

Comment: i am using .js@mongo (12345 is not much important here, this is just a select criteria i.e. employee id 12345)

Comment: just fyi, just have found that it is called 'associative array'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prepare your query in function of your need :

```
let projection : {};
for(let i = 0; i < numberOfValue; i++) {
    Object.assing(projection, {
        ["fields"+i]: 1
    });
}
db.employee.find({_id: "12345"}, projection, function(err, result) {

});
```